# How much space is required for a complete install of cturtle-base?

Tags: ros, installation, cturtle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am installing it on my beagleboard ubuntu distro. I need to know how big of an sdcard I need.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9159/how-much-space-is-required-for-a-complete-install-of-cturtle-base?/) by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2011-02-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I can recall, together with system dependencies, it would be around 1GB-1,5GB. But I cannot say exactly, maybe someone else still using cturtle (which I'm not) can tell better.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I missed it somehow you're installing it on a BeagleBoard. In this case I can say exactly how much you need as I'm doing the exact same thing (BB-xM).

Ubuntu 10.04 minimal needs 400MB [link](http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu#Lucid_10.04.2). I had problems installing Maverick, so I recommend Lucid. You'll need more or less 1GB-1,5GB for ROS, depending on which stacks you install. It's not ROS, but rather it's system dependencies that need more space. I have 4GB microSD's, they're just fine.

Also, read [REP108](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0108.html). You can now install many variants of ROS depending on your needs. You do it by replacing the variant variable with the one of your choice in [1.2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/SVN):

rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=**YOURVARIANT, EG mobile**&overlay=no"

Cheers, Tom

---

Originally posted by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) with karma: 1079 on 2011-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend using Diamondback.  The debs are about 50% smaller.

Also, the answer your question a bit better:

There is no 'base' variant in Diamondback.  We broke it into smaller configurations, for use cases like the one you describe.  These configurations range from 193M for the 'robot' variant (robot-generic libraries) to 1.2GB (simulators, visualizers, the works).

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-02-22**:
Yes, and the packaging granularity is better, so you probably end up with fewer stacks.